# AWS Cognito - Run Lambda after admin-created user is confirmed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am implementing a process where an admin can invite a user to my platform. I have a lambda that creates a user in Cognito using `AdminCreateUser` and then sends an invitation email to the recipient with a temporary password and a link to sign in. They can then sign in and set a new password, confirming their account. I have implemented the flow outlined in the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-user-accounts.html).

When the admin invites the user, an entry in DynamoDB is created for the user with the `pending` attribute set to `true`. I want to set this to `false` when the user completes the `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` challenge to complete this process.

I initially thought the `PostConfirmation` Lambda trigger would work perfectly for this use case but after further reading I discovered this is not triggered after users created by `AdminCreateUser` calls get confirmed.

Is there any way to capture the event of a user completing the `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` challenge without the client self-reporting that they've done so?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to implement same functionality but my lambda is getting timedout when I call `const command = new AdminCreateUserCommand(params); const response = await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.send(command);`

I have assigned below policy to the Lambda. Can you Please me with the right permission.

```
 {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser",
                    "cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:*:*:userpool/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS documentation says:

> You create custom workflows by assigning AWS Lambda functions to user pool triggers. When you use the RespondToAuthChallenge API action, Amazon Cognito invokes any functions that are assigned to the following triggers: post authentication, pre token generation, define auth challenge, create auth challenge, and verify auth challenge

I'd say that you need to handle any of those triggers and customize the behaviour.